# how to get $state.go params in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I use ui-router to be the route,but when I use $state.go(),I can redirect but cannot get the params I've passed,like this

```js
    .....
    $state.go('detail',{people_id : people_id});
```

In official APIs,it says that I can pass a map as parameter which will populate $stateParams,but it doesn't work in my app

```js
angular.module('xx').controller('aaaa',['$scope','$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams){
  console.log($stateParams);  //empty obj  
}])
```

So what the problem probably is? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In configuration you need to define url property to accept parameter

```
$stateProvider.state('detail', {
   url: 'people/detail/:id'
   ...
});
```